# altering order total in the commerce cart

Tags: cart, price, commerce

I am Trying this to change price in the cart:

```
    function mymodule_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh($line_item, $order_wrapper){
    if($line_item->type == 'product') {

        $line_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line_item);
        $entity = $commerce_product = $line_wrapper->commerce_product->value();
       $product_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $entity);

         $cprice = $product_wrapper->field_totalprice->value();
         $cprice *=100;

         $line_item->commerce_unit_price[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['amount'] = $cprice;

         // Alter the base_price component.
         $line_item->commerce_unit_price[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['data']['components']['0']['price']['amount'] = $cprice;
         $line_wrapper->save();


         }
}
```

After "Add to cart" cart total sum = base price, then after the second refresh admin/commerce/orders/carts price becomes = field_totalprice and after the third refresh cart total in the page changes to field_totalprice.

How can I change price with the "Add to cart" button?

Comment: maybe interesting? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46254/alter-cart-unit-price-and-total-amount

Comment: found some usefull information there, finally it helped! Thanks a lot!